# PrimeFaces AutoComplete changing default size

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to change the size of the autoComplete (primefaces 3.3), I tried all the below options but the size remains the same.

```
size="600"
Style="width:600px;"
StyleClass > css file with width:600px;
```

but none of them increases the size, so how do i do it.

Note: I noticed that if I specify (width > PanelGrid size) then the panel grid size changes automatically but autoComplete is still in default size.

Update: 
my autoComplete code

```
<p:autoComplete id="autoTest" value="#{testMB.selectedTest}" 
completeMethod="#{testMB.completeTest}" var="test" 
itemLabel="#{test.name}" itemValue="#{test}" converter="#{testConverter}"
forceSelection="TRUE"  queryDelay="1000" multiple="TRUE" size="600" 
process="@this">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using the below css

```
.ui-autocomp .ui-inputfield {
clear: left;
cursor: text;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
min-height: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 250px;
}
```

Just need to make sure that the selection doesn't exceed 250px, otherwise the close icon + extra text will not be visible.

Note: i got this from primeface css file

Answer (score 16):

I changed the default size for AutoComplete in Primefaces 5.2 by using the `inputStyle` attribute.

Example:

```
inputStyle="width: 100px"
```

Answer (score 7):

It is just need to change of `size` ;

```
     size="30"

    <p:autoComplete id="yourId" value="#{YourBean.value}" completeMethod="#{YurBean.complete}" size="30"/>
```

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work, check the updated code.

Answer (score 5):

To change the size of AutoComplete., you need to override the primefaces' default styleClass for AutoComplete.
Using firebug you can find out the styleclass name exactly. If you inspect the AutoComplete Element by using firebug., you can override the styleclass like `.ui-autocomplete-input.ui-inputfield
{
    width : 50px !important;

}`

!important is noted here to insist to carry high priority.

Answer (score 3):

Above all solutions does not work if we use `[multiple]="true"` directive.
In addition this question also asked in primeNg forums and there is no solution.

If you do not use above `[multiple]="true"` directive
Below solutions will work.

- `[style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}"`
- `class="p-autocomplete"` and in style file you can define this class as  `.p-autocomplete{ width: 100%; }`

Please check all of them.

Comment: Using [style]="{'width':'100%'}"  AND [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

use like this:

```
<p:autoComplete 
  ...
  style = "width: 100%"
  inputStyle = "width: 100%" />
```

just change 100% for the size you need in pixels..

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to change the width of p:autoComplete with [multiple]="true".

First, inspect the html and css code generated by Primefaces with your browser and look for the style to p:autoComplete. In my case, using Primefaces 6.1, the style is defined like this:

`.ui-autocomplete-multiple-container.ui-inputfield {...`

Then, use the id of the autoComplete in your style file in this way:

`#myAutoCompleteId .ui-autocomplete-multiple-container.ui-inputfield {
    width: 330px !important;
}`

This way you can get a different width for every autoComplete.

Comment: You could also add a class attribute in case you'd like to override multiple ones with the same with.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way I know is this:
add a style tag to your page
put this class in it :
.ui-inputfield
with this attribute:
width:600px;

but beware by this you will change all the inputs that are in your page
:)

Answer (score 0):

I know is long time but! after digging in styles, these worked for me in multiple autocomplete for PF 6.1:

```
.ui-autocomplete{
width: 100% !important;
}
.ui-autocomplete-input{
width: 100% !important;
}
.ui-autocomplete-multiple {
width: 98% !important;
}
.p-autocomplete {
width: 98% !important;
}
.ui-autocomplete-multiple-container {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Adjust according your needs.